# I'm unable to get the authorization code when trying to authenticate an application with OpenIdDict

Tags: c#, openiddict, asp.net-identity-3

I made an authorization server using OpenIdDict and it all seems to be working okay. It works when i call it using Postman, Swagger and [www.oidcdebugger.com](http://www.oidcdebugger.com).

However, when I try to call it from my own application I can't seem to find the "code" which should be returned so I can then use it in the call the token exchange.

This is my first time using OpenIdDict and .NET Core so I'm not 100% exactly sure what I'm doing but everything seems to be working and I have a feeling I'm just missing something that should be obvious.

```
            var user = HttpContext.User?.Identity?.Name;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var authorizationToken = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"web-client:901564A5-E7FE-42CB-B10D-61EF6A8F3654"));

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new("Basic", authorizationToken);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new("application/json")); // This might need to be adjusted, depending on your response format

                var urlAuthorize = new Uri("https://localhost:7000/connect/authorize");
                var paramAuthorize = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"client_id", "web-client"},
                    {"client_secret","901564A5-E7FE-42CB-B10D-61EF6A8F3654"},
                    {"response_type","code"},
                    {"grant_type","code"},
                    {"redirect_uri", "https://localhost:7002/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html"},
                    {"state", "VHVlIEZlYiAyNyAyMDI0IDA2OjUwOjUzIEdNVC0wNTAwIChFYXN0ZXJuIFN0YW5kYXJkIFRpbWUp"}
                };
                var encodedContentAuthorize = new FormUrlEncodedContent(paramAuthorize);
                var responseAuthorize = await client.PostAsync(urlAuthorize, encodedContentAuthorize).ConfigureAwait(false);

                responseAuthorize.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                return Ok();
            }
```

I tried the code above and it all runs ok, I just don't know how to find the authorization code.

Comment: if you mean the Status Code, it's in the responseAuthorize.StatusCode field. if you mean the returned body of the request you get it like `var content = await responseAuthorize.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`. Then extract what you need from there. Add null check for Content of course.

Comment: This was a problem with my own lack of understanding. The authentication code is not available at the point where I was looking for it. It is returning the challenge page, I needed to enter the client_id and client_secret into the challenge page and then submit. And then the authentication code is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with my own lack of understanding. The authentication code is not available at the point where I was looking for it. It is returning the challenge page, I needed to enter the client_id and client_secret into the challenge page and then submit. And then the authentication code is returned.